# What's the intended use of @JvmSynthetic in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, java-interop, synthetic

I have come across the [`@JvmSynthetic`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-synthetic/index.html) annotation in kotlin-stdlib, and I'm wondering what it is for, but, unfortunately, it is undocumented. (UPD: it was at that moment)

As far as I understand, applying it to a program element will add the `synthetic` modifier to the corresponding bytecode elements. As a consequence, the element becomes invisible from Java:

```
class MyClass {
    @JvmSynthetic
    fun f() { }
}
```

Somewhere in Java code:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.f() // Error: cannot resolve method f()
```

But the same elements are still visible in Kotlin code:

```
val c = MyClass()
c.f() // OK
```

Is hiding declarations from non-Kotlin sources a valid use of `@JvmSynthetic`? Is it the intended use? What are the other appropriate use cases?

Since `@JvmSynthetic` hides functions from Java, they cannot be overridden in Java either (and when it comes to an `abstract` member, the calls then result into `AbstractMethodError`). Given that, can I use `@JvmSynthetic` to prohibit overriding members of a Kotlin class in Java sources?

Comment: I use it to hide declarations from Java, especially for those which are `@PublishedApi internal`, i. e. accessible in inline functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, to answer what synthetic methods actually *are*, let's have a look at the [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1):

> **11.** A construct emitted by a Java compiler must be marked as *synthetic* if it does not correspond to a construct declared explicitly or implicitly in source code, unless the emitted construct is a class initialization method (JVMS §2.9).

The `@JvmSynthetic` annotation does exactly that: prevent access from source code. The method will still appear in reflection and is then marked as synthetic.

More precisely, from [the Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-synthetic/) (emphasis mine):

> #### `@JvmSynthetic`
>
> Sets `ACC_SYNTHETIC` flag on the annotated target in the Java bytecode.
>
> **Synthetic targets become inaccessible for Java sources at compile time while still being accessible for Kotlin sources.** Marking target as synthetic is a binary compatible change, already compiled Java code will be able to access such target.
>
> This annotation is intended for *rare* cases when API designer needs to hide Kotlin-specific target from Java API while keeping it a part of Kotlin API so the resulting API is idiomatic for both.

As described in the last paragraph, `@JvmSynthetic` is a tool for API design, which lets a library writer avoid automatic generation of Java equivalents. Probably the most popular use cases are Kotlin-only features, such as operator overloading, `componentN()` methods or properties, which may have a more idiomatic way to be exposed in Java.

It is noteworthy that the target of this annotations are property setters/getters, functions and fields -- basically everything that translates in Java to a method.

```
@Target([
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER,
    AnnotationTarget.FIELD])
annotation actual class JvmSynthetic
```

Answer (score 12):

In plain Java, `synthetic` methods are generated by the `javac` compiler. Normally the compiler must create synthetic methods on nested classes, when fields specified with the private modifier are accessed by the enclosing class.

Given the following class in java:

```
public final class SyntheticSample
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        SyntheticSample.Nested nested = new SyntheticSample.Nested();
        out.println("String: " + nested.syntheticString);
    }

    private static final class Nested
    {
        private String syntheticString = "I'll become a method!";
    }
}
```

when the `SyntheticSample` class accesses the `nested.syntheticString` field, it is indeed calling a static `synthetic` method generated by the compiler (named something like `access$100`).

Even if Kotlin exposes a `@JvmSynthetic` annotation that is able to "force" the creation of synthetic methods, I advice to not using it in normal "user" code. Synthetic methods are low-level tricks made by the compiler, and we should never rely on such things in everyday code. I think it's there to support other parts of the standard library, but you should ask the JetBrains guys directly if you're curious (try on the official [Kotlin Discussion Forum](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/))

Comment: Well, I agree it looks like a dangerous tool that needs careful handling, but still it's a part of `kotlin-stdlib`, it's a public API. It makes me think there should be use cases for `@JvmSynthetic` which an ordinary developer (or maybe  a library/tools developer) may encounter. Also, `synthetic` methods are used broader by `javac` then just for nested classses: at least for overriding a method with a different signature (including generic methods overridden with non-generic ones).