# Inline function cannot access non-public-API: @PublishedApi vs @Suppress vs @JvmSynthetic

Tags: inline, kotlin, public, java-synthetic-methods

In Kotlin, when I have a non-public member and an `inline fun` that calls it, there's a compilation error saying:

> Error:(22, 25) Kotlin: Public-API inline function cannot access non-public-API `private fun f(): Unit` defined in `com.example`

I found several ways to call my function inside a public `inline fun`, but which is the best way to do it?

Suppose I have a `private fun f() { }`. Then the options I found are:

- `fun f() { }`

  Just make it public. This is the baseline solution, but if the others turn out to have major disadvantages, this can end up the best one.
- `@PublishedApi internal fun f() { }`

  Introduced in [Kotlin 1.1-M04](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/12/kotlin-1-1-m04-is-here/), the annotation can be applied to an internal member, making it effectively public. The implication I noticed is that any library user will still be able to call it from Java code, that's what I don't like about it.
- `@Suppress("NON_PUBLIC_CALL_FROM_PUBLIC_INLINE") inline fun g() { f() }`

  Found in [the stdlib sources](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/19fa2f51ea893d2763846343fe66bd6ac1739ec7/libraries/stdlib/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L921), this annotation seems to suppress the error when applied to the calling function. But what are its limitations? Can it only be used for `inline` functions? Will the resulting program fail under some circumstances? I tried to call a non-inline function from an inline one with this trick, and it worked, but it looks suspicious.
- `@JvmSynthetic @PublishedApi internal fun f() { }`

  Combine the second solution with the *synthetic* flag in the bytecode. I'm not sure if this is a [correct usage of `@JvmSynthetic`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022275/whats-the-intended-use-of-jvmsynthetic-in-kotlin), but this appears to hide the function from Java code, which solves the problem of the `@PublishedApi internal`.

So, which of these solutions is the best way call a non-public function from a public inline one? What are the downsides of each solution that I don't see?

Comment: `@PublishedApi internal` should be declared on your private member, not on the inline function

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`@PublishedApi internal` is the intended way of exposing non-public API for use in public inline functions.

That `@PublishedApi internal` member becomes effectively public and its name *doesn't* get mangled (if you noticed the opposite, please file a bug).

`@Suppress("NON_PUBLIC_CALL_FROM_PUBLIC_INLINE")` is a band-aid workaround in the lack of `@PublishedApi` based on suppressing an error and therefore isn't recommended. With the introduction of `@PublishedApi` this suppression is going to be cleaned from the standard library.

`@JvmSynthetic` combined with `@PublishedApi` is an interesting approach, however it can cause some problems while debugging, though I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Right, now I see that `@PublishedApi internal` leaves the names intact, I was mistaken. By the way, is the IDE supposed to hide the `@PublishedApi internal` members from completion or discourage their usage someway? And, just out of curiosity, what was wrong with `@Suppress("NON_PUBLIC_CALL_FROM_PUBLIC_INLINE")`?

Comment: @hotkey Any follow-up on whether or not using `@JvmSynthetic` in combination with `@PublishedApi` causes any problems?

Comment: @StevenJeuris, I faced none, though I can't say I used that combination much. Well, none of my experiments aimed to detect trouble showed any.

Comment: @hotkey `@Suppress("NON_PUBLIC_CALL_FROM_PUBLIC_INLINE")`  this is not just to get rid of the warning right? I mean it does what `@PublishedApi` is intended to do "making the member *effectively* public", am I right?