# How can I store reified type data in instance fields in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, reification

I'm currently writing a DSL for a library and I'd like to supply type metadata using reified type parameters like this:

```
    val config = Config.create()
            .consumerFor<MyType>{
              // consume
            }
```

My problem is that i can only use the `reified` keyword in `inline` functions and in an `inline` function I can't use instance fields like this:

```
    inline fun <reified T> consumerFor(consumer: (T) -> Unit) {
        consumers.put(T::class.java, consumer)
        return this
    }
```

because I get an error:

> Public-API inline function cannot access non-public-API 'private final val consumers...

It seems so far that I can't use reified type parameters where they would be most useful. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Public `inline` functions cannot use `private` declarations directly, because, when inlined at the call sites outside the class, the usages will have incorrect access level (on JVM, a `private` member of a class cannot be accessed from outside).

What you can do is use [the `internal` visibility](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#visibility-modifiers) in Kotlin: on JVM, the members with this visibility modifier will be compiled into public members with their names mangled (therefore still visible but not easy-to-call from Java), and the Kotlin compiler will at least control the usages from the Kotlin code.

There are a few ways to access an `internal` member from within a `public inline fun`, see this question: [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892715/inline-function-cannot-access-non-public-api-publishedapi-vs-suppress-vs-jvm)

In your particular case, I would prefer doing it with [`@PublishedApi`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-published-api/):

```
private val consumers = mutableMapOf<Class<*>, Any>()

@PublishedApi
internal fun <T> putConsumer(clazz: Class<out T>, consumer: (T) -> Unit) {
    consumers.put(clazz, consumer)
}

inline fun <reified T> consumerFor(noinline consumer: (T) -> Unit): C {
    putConsumer(T::class.java, consumer)
    return this
}
```

Or, if you don't mind exposing `consumers` with `@PublishedApi`, then you can do it as follows:

```
@PublishedApi
internal val consumers = mutableMapOf<Class<*>, Any>()

inline fun <reified T> consumerFor(noinline consumer: (T) -> Unit): C {
    consumers.put(T::class.java, consumer)
    return this
}
```

Comment: This will be fine, thank you. This is just a configuration class with final fields so I don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

If all that you need the reified type parameter for is to reflect its java class, then you can manage with a non-inline overload with additional `Class<T>` parameter.

```
inline fun <reified T> consumerFor(noinline consumer: (T) -> Unit) =
    consumerFor(T::class.java, consumer)

fun <T> consumerFor(key: Class<T>, consumer: (T) -> Unit) = apply {
    consumers.put(key, consumer)
}
```

This way you haven't expose `consumers` property effectively published. The bonus point is that you can call that non-inline overload also from Java.