# Simple service locator with generic type parameters in Kotlin

Tags: design-patterns, kotlin, inversion-of-control, service-locator

I followed [these instructions](https://www.baeldung.com/java-service-locator-pattern) to create a simple service locator, adapted to Kotlin and simplified even more for the purpose of my question:

```
object ServiceLocator {

    @JvmStatic
    fun getService(serviceName: String): Any {
        val service = lookupService(serviceName)

        if (service != null) {
            return service
        }

        throw UnknownServiceException()
    }

    private fun lookupService(serviceName: String): Any? {
        if (serviceName.equals("MyService")) {
            return MyService()
        }

        return null
    }
}
```

I can use it as follows:

```
val myService = ServiceLocator.getService("MyService") as IMyService
```

The problem I have with this is `myService` is of type `Any`. I'd prefer it if `getService` returned the actual type instead. Ideally, I'd like to use it like so:

```
val myService = ServiceLocator.getService<IMyService>()
```

Or, if that's not possible, something like this would be fine:

```
val myService = ServiceLocator.getService(IMyService::class)
```

I can't figure out how to make the generic type parameters work. This is what I tried:

```
@JvmStatic
fun <T> getService(): T {
    val service = lookupService<T>()

    if (service != null) {
        return service
    }

    throw UnknownServiceException()
}

private fun <T> lookupService(): T? {
    if (T::class == IMyService::class) {
        return MyService()
    }

    return null
}
```

The compiler is complaining about two things:

1. On `T::class`, it complains "Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead."
2. On `return MyService()`, it says "Type mismatch. Required: T? Found: MyService"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the type, `T`, at runtime without having to pass the class in (e.g. `ServiceLocator.getService(IMyService::class)`), you have to use a [reified type parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters). Implicitly this means you have to change your methods to be [inline functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#inline-functions).  Doing that you could update your code to the below:

```
@JvmStatic
inline fun <reified T> getService(): T {
    val service = lookupService<T>()

    if (service != null) {
        return service
    }

    throw UnknownServiceException()
}

inline fun <reified T> lookupService(): T? {
    if (T::class == IMyService::class) {
        return MyService() as T
    }

    return null
}
```

Comment: This means `lookupService` has to be public as well. Is it possible to keep it private?

Comment: See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892715/inline-function-cannot-access-non-public-api-publishedapi-vs-suppress-vs-jvm). Hope that helps.