# How to hide Kotlin's lateinit var backing field from Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

In Kotlin, suppose, I have class:

```
class MyKotlinClass {
    lateinit var field: String
}
```

According to [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#instance-fields):

> Late-Initialized properties are also exposed as fields. The visibility of the field will be the same as the visibility of lateinit property setter.

I can use in **java** code either `myKotlinClass.field` or `myKotlinClass.getField()`. I want to disable field access and remain only access through *getter* and *setter*.

How can I achieve this and remain **lateinit** modifier?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`@JvmSynthetic`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-synthetic/index.html) that hides declarations from Java (and not from Kotlin). Just [annotate the backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) of the property:

```
@field:JvmSynthetic
lateinit var field: String
```

Though the field will remain `public` in the bytecode, it will also have the `synthetic` modifier, which prevents it from being used in Java sources. However, the field seems to be still accessible through reflection at runtime.

See also: another [question about `@JvmSynthetic`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022275/whats-the-intended-use-of-jvmsynthetic-in-kotlin) (though no definite answer there).

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I need.

Comment: I checked the generated byte code with Kotlin 1.0.6, and the backing field was still public

Comment: @voddan, but it should now have the `synthetic` modifier, does it? With this modifier, its usages in Java sources should become invalid.

Comment: @voddan, like this: `public synthetic Ljava/lang/String; s`. Or have you found any way to reference the field from Java?

Comment: @hotkey the field appears to have the `ACC_SYNTHETIC` on it. Let me check if I can access it from Java

Comment: @hotkey you were absolutely correct, sorry for the `-1`. Please edit your A (add a space somewhere :) so I could upvote it

Comment: @voddan, no problem, updated the answer with more details on what this does. :)

Comment: Is there any way to hide the generated getter and setter as well without setting those as private?

Answer (score 2):

The classical solution to this problem would be to use [property delegation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#delegated-properties):

```
import kotlin.properties.Delegates

class MyKotlinClass {
    var field: String by Delegates.notNull()
}
```

This code does exactly what you asked for in the question

Comment: Thank you for an alternative solutions. I've also checked this discussion https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/notnull-delegate-vs-lateinit/1923 - to see the actual difference between `lateinit` and `Delegates.notNull()`

Answer (score 1):

The visibility of `lateinit` field is derived from the visibility of setter of the corresponding property, so another option is to have a property with non-public setter:

```
lateinit var field: String
    private set
```

The drawback of this approach is that the setter itself becomes inaccessible outside of the class.