# How to force some method to be visible only to kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, visible

I want some method to be visible only to kotlin code and not to Java code.

For example, here is a method `fun method(){}` that can only be called in kotlin code and cannot be called in Java code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve exactly what you want by using the [`@JvmSynthetic`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-synthetic/index.html) annotation. It marks the element with the [`synthetic` flag](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-synthetic-class-method-field/) in the JVM bytecode, and its usage becomes an error in Java sources (not quite sure about other JVM languages, needs checking, but likely it will work as well):

```
@JvmSynthetic
fun f() { /*...*/ }
```

The marked element can still be used in Kotlin normally.

Unfortunately, `@JvmSynthetic` cannot be used to mark a class (it has no `CLASS` target).

See more:

- [What's the intended use of @JvmSynthetic in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022275/whats-the-intended-use-of-jvmsynthetic-in-kotlin) (no answer there, but the effect is described in the question)
- [Inline function cannot access non-public-API: @PublishedApi vs @Suppress vs @JvmSynthetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892715/inline-function-cannot-access-non-public-api-publishedapi-vs-suppress-vs-jvm), about how it can be used to hide effectively public internal members.

Answer (score 1):

Some methods in Kotlin stdlib are marked `inline` with the `@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly` annotation. That makes the compiler to inline them into the kotlin code without generating corresponding methods in JVM classes.

This trick is used for reducing method count on stdlib. This is a dangerous solution and can cause problems with separate compilation when used incorrectly.

The catch: the `@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly` annotation is internal and can be used only in the standard library. I know of no plans of releasing it into the public API.

TL;DR: You can do it, but only if you are contributing to Kotlin stdlib